Using input.float to Change Timezone
I'm utilizing the 'D' variable when selecting the timeframe of my request.security. That by default utilizes UTC daily times. I want my script to run off of UTC-4 instead. Below is the script.
//Modified by CAM
//@version=5
indicator(title="MTF High/Low", shorttitle="High/Low", overlay=true)

//DEFINE TimeFrame
TOOLTIP01 = "Enter timezone offset (+ or -) based of UTC"
hoursOffsetInput = input.float(0.0, "Timezone offset (in hours)", minval = -12.0, maxval = 14.0, step =     0.5, tooltip = TOOLTIP01)

// DAILY
activeD = input(true, title="Show On Chart D")
pricehighD = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1], gaps=barmerge.gaps_off,     lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
pricelowD = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[1], gaps=barmerge.gaps_off,     lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
// Daily Plots
plot(activeD and pricehighD ? pricehighD : na, title="Previous Daily High", style=plot.style_steplinebr,     linewidth=1, color=color.white)
plot(activeD and pricelowD ? pricelowD : na, title="Previous Daily Low", style=plot.style_steplinebr,     linewidth=1, color=color.white)

You can see that I tried entering an input.float in order to be able to select my timezone and alter the time that my script starts printing each day, but I don't know how to get my input.float into my request.security function in order for it to actually take effect when plotting.
Indicator plotting using UTC not UTC-4

The first ordinary session bar of the day will always be the same. It doesn't matter your UTC.

for test and debug, you can try session.isfirstbar_regular
